# How is logging for EF Core configured in the CleanArchitecture Solution?

Tags: logging, entity-framework-core, ardalis-cleanarchitecture

I can see informational logs for database commands executed through EF Core, but I don't see how it's been configured in the solution.

[image]

I was expecting to see logging for EF Core configured in `AppDbContext.cs` but it's not there. I do see where logging is configured for Serilog in `Program.cs` but there is nothing specific for EF Core.

How is logging generated for EF Core?